# SQL "IN" statement for multiple columns

Tags: sql, distinct

I would like to filter Name,X combinations for which is never X=Y
Let's assume the following table:

```
*Name*     *X*      *Y*
   A        2        1
   A        2        2   <--- fulfills requirement for Name=A, X=2
   A       10        1
   A       10        2
   B        3        1
   B        3        3   <--- fulfills requirement for Name=B, X=3
   B        1        1   <--- fulfills requirement for Name=B, X=1
   B        1        3
```

So I would like to return the combination Name=A, X=10 for which X=Y is never true.
This was my approach (which is syntactically incorrect)

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE NAME
     , X NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT NAME
                       , X 
                 FROM TABLE 
                 WHERE X=Y)
```

My problem is the where statement which cannot handle multiple columns. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: use `EXISTS` to do this.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put the columns into parentheses

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (NAME, X) NOT IN (SELECT NAME, X 
                        FROM TABLE WHERE X=Y);
```

The above is ANSI standard SQL but not all DBMS support this syntax though.

A `distinct` is not necessary for a sub-query for `IN` or `NOT IN`.

However `NOT EXISTS` with a co-related sub-query is very often faster that an `NOT IN` condition.

Comment: I feel ashamed, that I did not try that :). But this works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I use this on SQL Server

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (SELECT NAME + ';' + X)
    NOT IN (SELECT NAME + ';' + X
        FROM TABLE WHERE X = Y);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use two condition to achieve this

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE NAME NOT IN(
    SELECT a.NAME FROM TABLE a WHERE a.X=a.Y
) AND X NOT IN (
    SELECT b.X FROM TABLE b WHERE b.X=b.Y
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE T 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NAME
                  ,X 
              FROM TABLE t2 
              WHERE t1.Name=t2.Name
                    AND t1.X=t2.Y)
```

This will check if there is such a record